# RSpec pending groups/tests results in non-zero exit status

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec3

I have a set of rspec groups + examples, with a few groups and examples marked pending using the `pending: 'Some notes about why'` approach to marking them as such.

My suite runs, and successfully reports:

```
Finished in 35.63 seconds (files took 6.51 seconds to load)
65 examples, 0 failures, 26 pending
```

Unfortunately, it still returns a non-zero exit status, causing CI to still treat this as a failure:

```
petejohanson@xo-mb:~/Dev/xo-web/api $ echo $?
1
```

I don't want to ignore the non-zero code altogether, because then I will miss true test failures.

Anyone successfully used pending test and not had it give you problems with CI systems?

Comment: Could you add details of a test thats pending and what the rspec command you are running, I've got similar tests and I get a 0 exit code so I suspect its something to do with the way you trigger pending.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ctompkinson/6bbefd91cba33493f9dff57495b30ce2 is a basic working example of it returning 0.

Comment: Turns out this was caused by errors in before blocks that had the `:all` modifier. Switch those to all be regular `before do` blocks and the exit code was as expected.